# Help diagnosing repeated kernel panics

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic

I've been experiencing repeated kernel panics on my 2015 Macbook Pro. Sometimes the fans start spinning really loudly before the panic, sometimes not. Sometimes the screen jut goes black, sometimes it glitches in crazy ways (see picture).

I've taken the MacBook to a repair shop and they've looked at it four times(!), each time insisting that nothing is wrong with the hardware and that they can't replicate the error.

Here are the two latest panic logs:

panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff80169ee1e6): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80168e08f9, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000008, CR3: 0x000000001a88c000, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0
RAX: 0xffffff86aa225360, RBX: 0xffffffa0384440e0, RCX: 0x000000000000001f, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0xffffffb09fe73ef0, RBP: 0xffffffb09fe73ef0, RSI: 0x0000000000000002, RDI: 0xffffff80176a5510
R8:  0x000000000000001f, R9:  0xffffff86a937b360, R10: 0xffffff86a937b368, R11: 0xffffff86a84c9360
R12: 0x0000000000000005, R13: 0x0000000000000001, R14: 0xffffff86a84c9360, R15: 0xffffff80176a5300
RFL: 0x0000000000010007, RIP: 0xffffff80168e08f9, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000008, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x2, PL: 2, VF: 5

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffb09fe73910 : 0xffffff80168bab4d
0xffffffb09fe73960 : 0xffffff80169fd7e3
0xffffffb09fe739a0 : 0xffffff80169ede1a
0xffffffb09fe739f0 : 0xffffff801685fa2f
0xffffffb09fe73a10 : 0xffffff80168ba3ed
0xffffffb09fe73b30 : 0xffffff80168ba6d8
0xffffffb09fe73ba0 : 0xffffff80170bef9a
0xffffffb09fe73c10 : 0xffffff80169ee1e6
0xffffffb09fe73d90 : 0xffffff80169edecd
0xffffffb09fe73de0 : 0xffffff801685fa2f
0xffffffb09fe73e00 : 0xffffff80168e08f9
0xffffffb09fe73ef0 : 0xffffff80168ddaf1
0xffffffb09fe73f50 : 0xffffff80168dd3f6
0xffffffb09fe73fa0 : 0xffffff801685f13e

Process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
20D91

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 20.3.0: Thu Jan 21 00:07:06 PST 2021; root:xnu-7195.81.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: C86236B2-4976-3542-80CA-74A6B8B4BA03
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000016600000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff8016800000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000016610000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff8016810000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8016700000
System model name: MacBookPro12,1 (Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 343938685593
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
Uptime  : 0x000000501457dece
Sleep   : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
Wake    : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000328d644a1 0x0000000000000000
last started kext at 30061911846: >DiskImages.SparseDiskImage   493.0.0 (addr 0xffffff8018ec1000, size 8192)
loaded kexts:

> DiskImages.SparseDiskImage 493.0.0
> DiskImages.ReadWriteDiskImage  493.0.0
> DiskImages.CryptoEncoding  493.0.0
> DiskImages.UDIFDiskImage   493.0.0
> DiskImages.RAMBackingStore 493.0.0
> DiskImages.HTTPBackingStore    493.0.0
> DiskImages.FileBackingStore    493.0.0
> !AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
> AudioAUUC  1.70
> !APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
> AGPM   119
> X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
> @filesystems.autofs 3.0
> @fileutil   20.036.15
> !AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.2.2
> @AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.2.2
> pmtelemetry    1
> !AHDAHardwareConfigDriver  283.15
> LuaHardwareAccess  1.0.16
> !AHDA  283.15
> |IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
> usb.!UUserHCI  1
> |IO!BSerialManager  8.0.3d9
> @Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
> !AHV   1
> !ADiskImages2  1
> !A!IBDWGraphics    16.0.1
> !A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
> !AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
> !A!IBDWGraphicsFramebuffer 16.0.1
> !AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
> ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
> AGDCBacklightControl   6.2.2
> !ABacklight    180.3
> !AMCCSControl  1.14
> eficheck   1
> |Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    8.0.3d9
> !ASMCLMU   212
> !ACameraInterface  7.6.0
> !ALPC  3.1
> |IO!BUSBDFU 8.0.3d9
> |SCSITaskUserClient 436.40.6
> !UCardReader   511.60.2
> !AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
> @filesystems.tmpfs  1
> @filesystems.hfs.kext   556.60.1
> @BootCache  40
> @!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
> @!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
> @filesystems.apfs   1677.81.1
> !AAHCIPort 346
> !ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    4030.5
> AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
> @private.KextAudit  1.0
> !ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
> !ARTC  2.0
> !AACPIButtons  6.1
> !AHPET 1.8
> !ASMBIOS   2.1
> !AACPIEC   6.1
> !AAPIC 1.7
> @!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
> @nke.applicationfirewall    310
> |IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
> |EndpointSecurity   1
> DiskImages.KernelBacked    493.0.0
> !UAudio    401.4
> @kext.triggers  1.0
> !AGraphicsControl  6.2.2
> DspFuncLib 283.15
> @kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
> |IOSerial!F 11
> |IOAVB!F    930.1
> @!AGPUWrangler  6.2.2
> |IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
> |IOAccelerator!F2   439.52
> IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
> X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
> @!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.2.2
> !ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
> |IONDRVSupport  585
> !ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
> |Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   8.0.3d9
> |IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 8.0.3d9
> |IO!BHost!CTransport    8.0.3d9
> !AHDA!C    283.15
> |IOHDA!F    283.15
> |IOGraphics!F   585
> |IOAudio!F  300.6.1
> @vecLib.kext    1.2.0
> !ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
> IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
> !AThunderboltEDMSink   5.0.3
> !AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.1.4
> @plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    900.11
> |IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
> usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
> usb.cdc    5.0.0
> usb.networking 5.0.0
> usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
> !AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.1.4
> !AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.1.4
> !AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
> !ABSDKextStarter   3
> |IOSurface  289.3
> @filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
> !AXsanScheme   3
> |IOAHCIBlock!S  332
> !AActuatorDriver   4400.28
> |IOAHCI!F   294
> !AHIDKeyboard  223
> !AMultitouchDriver 4400.28
> !AInputDeviceSupport   4400.35
> !AHS!BDriver   4030.5
> IO!BHIDDriver  8.0.3d9
> !AHSSPIHIDDriver   61
> !AThunderboltNHI   7.2.8
> |IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.2
> |IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
> |IOSkywalk!F    1
> mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
> corecapture    1.0.4
> usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
> |IOUSB!F    900.4.2
> !AHSSPISupport 61
> !A!ILpssSpi!C  3.0.60
> !A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
> !A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
> !A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
> usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
> usb.!UXHCI 1.2
> !AEFINVRAM 2.1
> !AEFIRuntime   2.1
> |IOSMBus!F  1.1
> |IOHID!F    2.0.0
> $!AImage4   3.0.0
> |IOTimeSync!F   900.11
> |IONetworking!F 3.4
> DiskImages 493.0.0
> |IO!B!F 8.0.3d9
> |IOReport!F 47
> |IO!BPacketLogger   8.0.3d9
> $quarantine 4
> $sandbox    300.0
> @kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
> |CoreAnalytics!F    1
> !ASSE  1.0
> !AKeyStore 2
> !UTDM  511.60.2
> |IOUSBMass!SDriver  184.40.6
> |IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  436.40.6
> |IO!S!F 2.1
> |IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  436.40.6
> !AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
> @kext.CoreTrust 1
> !AFDEKeyStore  28.30
> !AEffaceable!S 1.0
> !ACredentialManager    1.0
> KernelRelayHost    1
> |IOUSBHost!F    1.2
> !UHostMergeProperties  1.2
> usb.!UCommon   1.0
> !ABusPower!C   1.0
> !ASEPManager   1.0.1
> IOSlaveProcessor   1
> !AACPIPlatform 6.1
> !ASMC  3.1.9
> |IOPCI!F    2.9
> |IOACPI!F   1.4
> watchdog   1
> @kec.pthread    1
> @kec.corecrypto 11.1
> @kec.Libm   1

LOG NUMBER TWO:

panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff80137ee1e6): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80136e09c1, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000000, CR3: 0x0000000241eeb045, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0
RAX: 0xffffff86a7760000, RBX: 0x000000000000000c, RCX: 0x0000000000000014, RDX: 0x000000000000000d
RSP: 0xffffffb09cab3d10, RBP: 0xffffffb09cab3d10, RSI: 0xffffff86a7760000, RDI: 0xffffff80144a5510
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x000000000000000f, R11: 0x0000000000000000
R12: 0xffffff80144a5300, R13: 0xffffff86a7760000, R14: 0x0000000000000001, R15: 0xffffffa03508cd68
RFL: 0x0000000000010086, RIP: 0xffffff80136e09c1, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000000, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x3, PL: 3, VF: 0

Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffb09cab3730 : 0xffffff80136bab4d
0xffffffb09cab3780 : 0xffffff80137fd7e3
0xffffffb09cab37c0 : 0xffffff80137ede1a
0xffffffb09cab3810 : 0xffffff801365fa2f
0xffffffb09cab3830 : 0xffffff80136ba3ed
0xffffffb09cab3950 : 0xffffff80136ba6d8
0xffffffb09cab39c0 : 0xffffff8013ebef9a
0xffffffb09cab3a30 : 0xffffff80137ee1e6
0xffffffb09cab3bb0 : 0xffffff80137edecd
0xffffffb09cab3c00 : 0xffffff801365fa2f
0xffffffb09cab3c20 : 0xffffff80136e09c1
0xffffffb09cab3d10 : 0xffffff80136db8c5
0xffffffb09cab3dd0 : 0xffffff80136df098
0xffffffb09cab3e40 : 0xffffff80136dec88
0xffffffb09cab3eb0 : 0xffffff80136dd40f
0xffffffb09cab3f00 : 0xffffff80136b24b5
0xffffffb09cab3f30 : 0xffffff801365f9fb

Process name corresponding to current thread: softwareupdated

Mac OS version:
20D91

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 20.3.0: Thu Jan 21 00:07:06 PST 2021; root:xnu-7195.81.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: C86236B2-4976-3542-80CA-74A6B8B4BA03
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000013400000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff8013600000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000013410000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff8013610000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8013500000
System model name: MacBookPro12,1 (Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 1102684329040
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
Uptime  : 0x00000100bd1b98b9
Sleep   : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
Wake    : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000907609584 0x0000000000000000
last started kext at 972756194523: >usb.!UUserHCI   1 (addr 0xffffff7fb3f9f000, size 102400)
last stopped kext at 886248988533: >usb.!UHostCompositeDevice   1.2 (addr 0xffffff8016448000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:

> usb.!UUserHCI  1
> |IO!BUSBDFU 8.0.3d9
> !AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
> AudioAUUC  1.70
> @filesystems.autofs 3.0
> X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
> !APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
> AGPM   119
> @fileutil   20.036.15
> !AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.2.2
> @AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.2.2
> pmtelemetry    1
> LuaHardwareAccess  1.0.16
> |IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
> |IO!BSerialManager  8.0.3d9
> !AHDA  283.15
> @Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
> !AHV   1
> !ADiskImages2  1
> eficheck   1
> !ACameraInterface  7.6.0
> !A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
> !ALPC  3.1
> !A!IBDWGraphics    16.0.1
> !ABacklight    180.3
> !AMCCSControl  1.14
> !ASMCLMU   212
> |Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    8.0.3d9
> !A!IBDWGraphicsFramebuffer 16.0.1
> !AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
> !UCardReader   511.60.2
> @filesystems.tmpfs  1
> @filesystems.hfs.kext   556.60.1
> @BootCache  40
> @!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
> @!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
> @filesystems.apfs   1677.81.1
> !AAHCIPort 346
> !ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    4030.5
> AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
> @private.KextAudit  1.0
> !ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
> !ARTC  2.0
> !AACPIButtons  6.1
> !AHPET 1.8
> !ASMBIOS   2.1
> !AACPIEC   6.1
> !AAPIC 1.7
> @!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
> @nke.applicationfirewall    310
> |IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
> |EndpointSecurity   1
> !UAudio    401.4
> usb.cdc    5.0.0
> usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
> @kext.triggers  1.0
> !AGraphicsControl  6.2.2
> |IOSerial!F 11
> |IOAVB!F    930.1
> DspFuncLib 283.15
> @kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
> @plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    900.11
> |IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
> @!AGPUWrangler  6.2.2
> |IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
> !ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
> !AHDA!C    283.15
> |IOHDA!F    283.15
> |IOAudio!F  300.6.1
> @vecLib.kext    1.2.0
> X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
> IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
> !ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
> |IONDRVSupport  585
> |Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   8.0.3d9
> |IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 8.0.3d9
> |IO!BHost!CTransport    8.0.3d9
> |IOAccelerator!F2   439.52
> @!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.2.2
> |IOGraphics!F   585
> usb.networking 5.0.0
> !AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.1.4
> !AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.1.4
> !AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
> !ABSDKextStarter   3
> |IOSurface  289.3
> @filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
> |IOAHCIBlock!S  332
> !AActuatorDriver   4400.28
> |IOAHCI!F   294
> !AHIDKeyboard  223
> !AMultitouchDriver 4400.28
> !AInputDeviceSupport   4400.35
> !AHS!BDriver   4030.5
> IO!BHIDDriver  8.0.3d9
> !AHSSPIHIDDriver   61
> !AThunderboltNHI   7.2.8
> |IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.2
> |IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
> |IOSkywalk!F    1
> mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
> corecapture    1.0.4
> |IOUSB!F    900.4.2
> !AHSSPISupport 61
> !A!ILpssSpi!C  3.0.60
> !A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
> !A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
> usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
> usb.!UXHCI 1.2
> !AEFINVRAM 2.1
> !AEFIRuntime   2.1
> |IOSMBus!F  1.1
> |IOHID!F    2.0.0
> $!AImage4   3.0.0
> |IOTimeSync!F   900.11
> |IONetworking!F 3.4
> DiskImages 493.0.0
> |IO!B!F 8.0.3d9
> |IOReport!F 47
> |IO!BPacketLogger   8.0.3d9
> $quarantine 4
> $sandbox    300.0
> @kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
> |CoreAnalytics!F    1
> !ASSE  1.0
> !AKeyStore 2
> !UTDM  511.60.2
> |IOUSBMass!SDriver  184.40.6
> |IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  436.40.6
> |IO!S!F 2.1
> |IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  436.40.6
> !AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
> @kext.CoreTrust 1
> !AFDEKeyStore  28.30
> !AEffaceable!S 1.0
> !ACredentialManager    1.0
> KernelRelayHost    1
> |IOUSBHost!F    1.2
> !UHostMergeProperties  1.2
> usb.!UCommon   1.0
> !ABusPower!C   1.0
> !ASEPManager   1.0.1
> IOSlaveProcessor   1
> !AACPIPlatform 6.1
> !ASMC  3.1.9
> |IOPCI!F    2.9
> |IOACPI!F   1.4
> watchdog   1
> @kec.pthread    1
> @kec.corecrypto 11.1
> @kec.Libm   1

[image]

Comment: Can you make the error happen?

Comment: Unfortunately not! It can occur when browsing, during installation of an uppdate or whenever. Video calls and games seems to increase the likelihood of a crash but it’s never predictable

Comment: Bummer - and I presume the screen is perfect except when the machine crashes?

Comment: Yes, it's only like that when it crashes, and even then only maybe 20% of the time

Answer (score 0):

The repair shop got tired of me constantly coming back and decided to replace the motherboard free of charge. The computer works fine now, so it was most likely a hardware error.

Comment: I had a similar problem and wasted many hours trying to persuade Apple it was defective.  Finally, they replaced the motherboard and the problem continued.  Traded in the laptop for another of the same model and no longer have the problem.